# expected conv2d_input to have shape [null,200,200,3] but got array with shape [1,220,220,3]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've created a model:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

I'm working with tensorflow.js, I've created a medical website, model.json and I want to check if it works fine, so I've picked some picture from validation folder and tried to predict if the patient is healthy or not.

```
<script>
    async function LoadModels(){  
           model = undefined;
           model = await tf.loadLayersModel("http://127.0.0.1:5500/model.json");
           const pr = document.getElementById('photo');
           const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(pr);
           const prediction = model.predict(tf.expandDims(image, 0));
           alert(prediction);
       }
       LoadModels();
</script>
```

Of course it gives me [1, 200, 200, 3] when I need [null, 200, 200, 3]. I tried to reshape it, but no luck.

Could you please help?

Comment: Read the error message carefully, it says 220, not 200, and that is why it errors.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Gosh, I've been working on the model and tensorflow.js stuff for like 10 hours straight, my brain was just blowing, thank you so much and sorry :D Now everything works fine. Thank you!